# Oracle Apex: Upload Wizard -> Exporting Apex_Collections error table to CSV file stops remainder of page from rendering

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have created an upload wizard to enter physician data into a staging area table.  On the Data Load Result page I am given a table showing all data that failed to upload.  A requirement is to have this table export as a CSV file.  I have successfully written the PL/SQL to do so; however, it only works if it is run as a process on the Data Load Results page pre-render before header section.  The code successfully exports the data to a CSV file, but stops the remainder of the page from rendering. I cannot figure out why the page will not render after the PL/SQL runs to export the CSV file. Below is the PL/SQL:

```
'''
    begin
    -- Set the MIME type
    owa_util.mime_header( 'application/octet', FALSE );
    -- Set the name of the file
    htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="emp.csv"');
    -- Close the HTTP Header
    owa_util.http_header_close;
    -- Loop through all rows in EMP
    for x in 
    (select * from apex_collections where collection_name ='LOAD_CONTENT' and c047 'FAILED'                 
    loop
     -- Print out a portion of a row,
     -- separated by commas and ended by a CR
     htp.prn(x.c001 ||','|| x.c002 ||','|| x.c003 ||','||
           x.c004 ||','|| x.c005 ||','|| x.c006 ||','||
           x.c007 ||','|| x.c008 ||','|| x.c009 ||','||
           x.c010 ||','|| x.c011 ||','|| x.c012 ||','||
           x.c013 ||','|| x.c014 ||','|| x.c015 ||','||
           x.c016 ||','|| x.c017 ||','|| x.c018 ||','||
           x.c019 ||','|| x.c020 ||','|| x.c021 ||','||
   x.c022 ||','|| x.c023 ||','|| x.c024 ||','||
   x.c025 ||','|| x.c026 ||','|| x.c027 ||','||
   x.c028 ||','|| x.c029 ||','|| x.c030 ||','||
   x.c031 ||','|| x.c032 ||','|| x.c033 ||','||
   x.c034 ||','|| x.c035 ||','|| x.c036 ||','||
   x.c037 ||','|| x.c038 ||','|| x.c040 ||','||
   x.c041 ||','|| x.c042 ||','|| x.c043 ||','||
   x.c044 ||','|| x.c045 ||','||
     chr(13));
end loop;
-- Send an error code so that the
-- rest of the HTML does not render
htmldb_application.g_unrecoverable_error := true;
end;

    '''
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ2Ky.png)

Comment: The code you posted has a comment "Send an error code so that the rest of the HTML does not render" before signaling an unrecoverable error.  That's designed to stop the rest of the page from loading.

Comment: Removed that line of code, did not resolve the issue :(

Comment: If you removed that line, I would expect that the rest of the page would render, it would just render as part of the CSV file.  Rather than going down the path you're travelling, could you just toss an interactive report on the page that reads from the collection and let the user download the data from that interactive report?

Comment: The browser interprets the HTTP headers to know how to present the downloaded data to the user. In your case you are telling the browser to expect a simple text file, named "emp.csv" - so you should expect to get no web page. The key to making this work is to change the way that your calling page invokes this process - i.e. open in a new window (instead of closing the APEX page).